# A.union и a.update - в чём разница?

Tags: python

Добрый день.

Изучаю  Python по видеолекциям,  дошёл до множеств, в примере упоминается метод по объединению

```
a.union
```

и

```
a.update
```

В чём принципиальная разница?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

union в качестве результат возвращает новое множество, не меняя исходные, а update ничего не возвращает, но добавит в первое множество элементы второго.

```
>>> a = set([1,2,3])
>>> b = set([2,3,4])
>>> print a.union(b)
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> print a
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> print b
set([2, 3, 4])

>>> a = set([1,2,3])
>>> b = set([2,3,4])
>>> print a.update(b)
None
>>> print a
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> print b
set([2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: То есть  при создании( union) нового множества выделяется дополнительно яйчейкав памяти ? а при (update) получиться расход памяти меньше ?

Comment: Не готов вам ответить, что именно происходит в интерпретаторе, но скорей всего так и есть. При создании нового множества с помощью union точно создастся новый объект и займет память.